# Second star to the right and straight on 'til morning

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, outer-space

Remember to look up at the stars and not down at your feet.
Try to make sense of what you see...

We look up at the same stars and see such different things.

[image]

So I looked up, *second to the right* he said.
What did I see?

**Here's a little rhyme to help you start**

> *Some numbers are important, others not, all letters are the two.
>
> Colors like red herrings, a lot, every single one 'cept blue!*

Comment: I was hoping with a name like yours', you would be involved with this tag!

Comment: Took me a little bit. Had to make the image. Hopefully it isn't too obscure and all, but then again, it is outer-space! (lol)    - also I'm hesitating in putting the trivia tag also, I'm afraid it might send people really off track, but a bit of it *can* help to start off.

Comment: Is the star in the upper left (directly right from the red 2) supposed to have no identifier?

Comment: Indeed, it is as designed. : )

Comment: Well then, the 2nd star to the right is missing an identifier.  That is what I see. :)

Comment: But in space, there is no up... and come to think of it, no right either...

Comment: @Kingrames Peter Pan was a postmodernist =)

Comment: Galactic equator?

Comment: His right, my left...

Comment: Sadly, I am somewhat colorblind =( So if the solution requires tracing the stars in order of their colour (which I just realized the stars might have)... -1

Comment: The solution does not require tracing stars in order of color. Most stars are all the same color anyway. If anything, one of the biggest clues to start it all has already been noticed by @APrough. The star with no identifier. - Hilariously, and I'm saying more than I wanted. Google 'might' help.

Comment: With a quick google of peter pan star it comes up with images of the two blue stars in the picture and for @Hackiisan its the unmarked star and the 7 up and to the right. I'm wondering if it's neverland

Comment: Not sure if it is coincidence or not, but if you start at the 7 star, count that numbers points going clockwise (assuming 1 at the top), and then trace that point to a star, then repeat the process with that new star, you eventually end up at the "L".

Comment: hmm, maybe you're on to something

Comment: Well, was my first time doing a puzzle like this, definitely would do a few elements differently now that I look back on it.   Btw, anyone noticed the two quotes other that the Peter Pan one?   Hope it was fun : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see

> the constellation Leo.  By starting at the "7" star (the second to the right in images of Peter Pan stars), and counting the number of points on that star, you will see another star pointing back.  Continue that process and you eventually end up at the "L" star.

Tracing the full line looks like this...

> [image: stars]

Which looks an awful lot like this...

> [image: leo]

Comment: Could you clarify what "counting the number of points" means?

Comment: So First star says 7.  start at top counting 1 going clockwise and counting to 7.  you should end up pointing to the left, at the 3 star.  again, starting at top of 3 star, count to 3 and you will be pointing down and to the right.  etc. etc.

Comment: Indeed it is. I was hoping the enigmatic tag would've pushed people to look up the peter pan quote and its relation to stars. I also was undecided on the use of letters. I wanted to put the letters L, E and O but it seemed too obvious so i switched the O to 0, I don't think anyone would've noticed it now, maybe putting all first letters of the 12 astrological signs would've been a better 'engimatic' clue. Hmm. Problem was once the image was posted, couldn't really modify it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting with lots of possible solutions. Currently I see 2 of them:

> There is a start marked as "L" on the right side. If that means left side,then left is right, right is left. So your words *"second to the right"* would mean second to the left, then the solution can be the red "2" star on the left or another star marked "2" on the bottom-left side (there are lots of possible ways of realizing what means 2nd)

And the second way (more possible)

> There is "E" on the top-right side. So if we connect "L" and "E" and assume that it shows the left direction, then upper side will become "left", bottom side will be the "right". And then *"second to the right "* can mean star marked 2 on the bottom side.

Comment: Nice to see someone is attempting :)    You are right to focus on the Peter Pan quote, however try fitting it with that suspiciously unidentified star.